# How to Show Negative Values to RightSide of Devexpress TextEdit

Tags: .net, devexpress, textedit

Actually,I need to Show only Numbers on `TextEdit` and It can be both Negative and Positive.
When I want that text to be Displayed to the Right.

So the Properties of my TextEdit are :

```
MaskType : Numeric
RightToLeft : Yes
```

Now,My Problem is,It is Showing Text in the Format like :

```
For Positive Values -> 888
For Negative Values -> 888-
```

I want that `Minus(-)` symbol to be displayed to be displayed before the `number(888)`.

- For Example -> -888

Can Anyone Help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`TextEdit.Properties.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment`

If you wish to change text alignment to right, set HAlignment to HorzAlignment.Far
instead of `RightToLeft: Yes`

I believe it will produce the desired result.